# How to add custom passwords to the Google Password manager?

Tags: password, android-11, oneplus

I’m using a OnePlus and want to add a custom password for a pdf I open frequently, I want to save this so I can easily access it and not type it over again. The native Password manager is not allowing me to do so, please help. Thanks

Comment: Based on [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill), I don't think there's a way to add custom passwords to Google Password Manager (service) since the prompt depends on the apps (clients), not files or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Well, do you have a third-party app you can recommend? Or maybe some other native service for OnePlus Phones?